# Spring boot is not reading environment variables on Linux server

Tags: linux, spring, maven, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variable for spring boot `Datasource` related properties.
`Datasource` properties are in `applicationcontext.properties` file.
I have tried several approaches to read environment properties which are set on linux server but failed to do so.

i have tried below things inside `datasourceset` method:

```
@Autowired private Environment env;
env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
```

or

```
System.getenv("spring.datasource.username");
```

But neither of them worked.

Main thing is everything working fine on local windows machine but not working on linux server.
I am able to set `env` variable on linux even I can see variable is set on `env` properties list bit whenever i try to read those properties its not returning any value.

Comment: try restarting the application? It might be possible that your process started before variables were set in the environment.

Comment: The environment variable should be named `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` else it won't work.